# Writing melodies with different verses

Tags: piano

My melody changes a little in each verse. How should I write these alternate melodies on a score, please? This is for a piece of children's music.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lyricist writing lines that scan would make your life easier! In the first line of verse two, *If your* [you mean **you're**] *lost and scared* could be changed to *If you are lost and scared*. Then it would scan like the other two verses.

I've corrected your musical spelling. I guessed that you meant the rhythms of lines 1 and 2 to be the same. Hope it's useful.

[image]

Comment: The little **1:** over bar seven shows than verse one is sung to the stems-up tune. If that bar had occurred in the *middle* of the line, I would have put the **1:** to the left of the crotchet rest, over the preceding barline. But coming at the *start* of a line, it needed to be separated from the key signature. The meaning is clear enough where it is.

Comment: Thank you so much that's so kind of you. I'm new to Sibelius. How do I add the rests above notes and also the extend line to continue the vocals, please? Really kind. https://app.box.com/s/o51oi99qjiko22uri6ip10hrdm1aljya

Comment: The bars with rests over the notes are written using two 'voices'. It would take me a long time to describe the process but if you search the Reference Guide for 'voices' you'll find it clearly explained. You may need to read about hiding notes/rests too. Those lines ('lyric lines') showing an extended syllable are made by hitting the space-bar while you're entering the lyrics. Sibelius handles lyrics really well and with a bit of practice you can enter them as fast as you can type.